# Archlinux vm on vmware workstation use hardware UTC instead time of windows10 host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, arch-linux, vmware-workstation

I have windows10 box, on that I install vmware workstation and create an archlinux vm on vmware workstation.

Problem is when I set to use UTC on archlinux with this command:

`ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime`

Then I have output of `timedatectl`:

               `Local time: Sun 2018-08-26 15:18:06 UTC
           Universal time: Sun 2018-08-26 15:18:06 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2018-08-26 15:18:07
                Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no`

But when I check with actual UTC time with https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc, It's at `08:43:34 UTC`, so I guess archvm used windows10 host box's time as its hardward time.

Then how would I change it to have same UTC time?

I've noticed that Virtualbox has feature `system->Hardware clock in UTC time` and I aslo have an archlinux vm on virtualbox, the same process as above and it has correct UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the time sync off, which is part of the VMTools, that syncs the VM's time to the host.

On the VM's settings, go to the Options tab.
Next, click VMware Tools and uncheck "Syncronize guest time with host"

You'll probably want to add an NTP server to the VM's OS settings so your clock stays accurate.

Comment: I don't use vmwaretools but I manged to solve this issue by using `ntp` to update time up to `UTC` instead of base on `localtime`.